# Find conversation not working in sequelize findOne

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, relationship

I have been struggling for days trying to find if a conversation exists between two users using Sequelize. I have relationships between `conversation`, `message`, `user` and `userConversations`. Here is how a table can look like:

[image]

Here is my `userConversations` table, what I want is find if there is an existing conversation between 2 or x users.

Here are the relationship and the query :

```
db.conversations.hasMany(db.messages, {
  foreignKey: 'conversationId',
});
db.messages.belongsTo(db.conversations);

db.conversations.belongsToMany(db.users, { through: db.userConversations });
db.users.belongsToMany(db.conversations, { through: db.userConversations });

db.conversations.hasMany(db.userConversations, {
  foreignKey: 'conversationId',
});
db.userConversations.belongsTo(db.conversations);

db.messages.belongsTo(db.users, { as: 'sender' });
```

Here is the `NOT` working query, what I want is check if there is an existing converstion for given user ids like `[2,3]` or `[1,3]` or  `[x, y, ...]`

```
  let conversationDB = await db.conversations.findOne({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.userConversations,
        where: { userId: { [Op.in]: [2, 3] } }, <=== HARDCODED [2,3] for the example
      },
  });
```

Here is the result I dont agree on :

```
{
   "id": 5,
   "userConversations": [
       {
           "id": 8,
           "conversationId": 5,
           "userId": 2
       }
   ]
}
```

I am expecting to match strictly `[2, 3]` so i am expecting to strictly have two entries, here is what i want

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "userConversations": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "conversationId": 6,
            "userId": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "conversationId": 6,
            "userId": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Also tried this but not working

```
let conversationDB = await db.conversations.findOne({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.userConversations,
        where: { userId: { 2 } },
      },
      {
        model: db.userConversations,
        where: { userId: 3 },
      },
    ],
    group: ['conversations.id'],
    having: Sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT userConversations.userId) = 2'),
  });
```

Any hint or ideas would be so helpful, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL an easy aggregate method is possible for your data model.

The logic is for the user a,b,c if we have a conversation whose count is 3 then the conversation exists between them.

```
select count(conversationId), userId, conversationId where userId in (1,2,3) group by conversationId having count(conversationId) = 3
```

So using this you can reverse find the conversation object.

Like,

```js
models.userConversations.findAll({
    attributes: ['userId', 'conversationId', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('conversationId')), 'conversationCount']],
    include: [
    {
        model: models.conversations,
        attributes: []
    }],
    where: { userId: { [Op.in]: [2, 3] } },
    group: ['conversationId'],
    having: { conversationCount: 2 }
});
```

I am little rusty in Sequelize so don't know if the syntax will work 100%. if it doesn't and you find the correct syntax comment and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it tells me `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "conversationCount" does not exist`, i will work to find a fix, thank you for you answer

Comment: oh there is a syntax eror in the attributes array. Edited. Now try.

Comment: I did try without the typo but still an error on `Error when findConversation from server: SequelizeDatabaseError: column "conversationCount" does not exist` m do you think we can use `having: { conversationCount: 2 },` like that ? It seems like this is the problem for some reason.

Comment: then you can create having using literals. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7975

`having: Sequelize.literal('count(conversationId) = 2')` or `having: Sequelize.literal('conversationCount = 2')`

Comment: sounds really great with `having: Sequelize.literal('conversationCount = 2')` or `having: Sequelize.literal('count(conversationId) = 2')` but it doesnt understand `conversationId` , `column "conversationid" does not exist` i will keep digging, thank you so much for your help my friend, i wish i could reward you

Comment: dont worry. after you figure it out, comment here. I will edit the answer for other people. Then you can choose the answer solution that will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time i dont have any errors but now nothing is being returned except `[]`

```
let conversationDB = await db.userConversations.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'conversationId',
      [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('conversationId')), 'conversationCount'],
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: db.conversations,
        attributes: [],
      },
    ],
    where: { userId: { [Op.in]: [1, 2] } },
    group: ['conversationId'],
    having: Sequelize.literal('count(conversation.id) = 2'),
  });
```

Here is user `userConversations` table :

[image]